# How can I route to a child route in Zend 3?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I use Zend Framework Version 3. I would like to redirect the request to a new route, and in more precisely to a childroute?

If it was only a "parent" route I would to this

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('name-of-route', []);
```

however I have a childroute I would like to redirect to. How can this be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this works the same as in ZF2, you use a `/` to denote the heirarchy:

```
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('name-of-route/name-of-child-route', []);
```